# Adding a fragment inside another fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want add a fragment inside another one dynamically .
the outer fragment is a **DialogFragment** :

```
public class MapFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener,
    OnMarkerDragListener {

FragmentManager fmanager;
Fragment fragment;
SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment;

public static MapFragmentDialog newInstance() {
    MapFragmentDialog f = new MapFragmentDialog();
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

    // *********** add myMapFragment

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // add a fragment
    MyMapFragment myFragment = new MyMapFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    myMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMap)).getMap();

    return v;
}
```

the **map_fragment** layout is like this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHelp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myfragment"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

my inner fragment **MyMapFragment** :

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_map_fragment, container, false);
    return myFragmentView;
}}
```

the **my_map_fragment** layout contain :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

i get an exception on getting the map fragment on my DialogFragment , a NullPointerException at this line

```
myMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMap)).getMap();
```

Comment: either `getActivity()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `findFragmentById(R.id.myMap)` returned null

Answer (score 2):

I remember seeing something about fragments in fragments working only dynamically and not by placing them XML. I think Abd El-Rahman El-Tama has the correct idea of using a frameLayout nstead of specifying a fragment directly

Answer (score 1):

To change the `Fragments` dynamically all what you need is

**1)** A `FrameLayout` in your `Layout` as following:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**2)** Initialize the `FrameLayout` into your `activity` as following:-

```
FrameLayout fragment = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment);
```

**3)** Start Fragment transaction as following:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, new MyFragment()).commit();
```

Or

```
FragmentManager fragMan = new FragmentManager();
fragMan.beginTransaction ();
fragMan.replace (R.id.fragment);
fragMan.commit ();
```

Comment: i can't access getSupportFragmentManager() from a DialogFragment , any suggestion ?

Comment: Try `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: it's not working , still getting nullPointerException

Comment: still the same.
i explain more : i have an activity where i call a fragment "MapFragmentDialog" , inside this fragment i want add another fragment dynamically "MyMapFragment" wich is a google map (i'm using support library v4)

Comment: If you are using `supportedLibraryV4` then, call `getSupportFragmentManager()` and import it. If you found problem again, add the full log or the lone after CausedBy: . Feel free to ask any questions and to vote up :) if you found my info useful

Comment: the problem is that my outer fragment extends "DialogFragment" , so in order to use getSupportFragmentManager() it has to extends FragmentActivity

Comment: Ok, then you can't access it directly. Now, call `getActivity ().getSupportFragmentManager ()......etc

Comment: still same problem , i can't get back the fragment that i have added dynamically.

Comment: I am afraid that you are not clear with your error or exception. I also tried to help you a lot. Maybe one vote up will represent you thank and time appreciation for me.

Comment: thx for your help anyway , in order to vote up for you ,i need 15 reputation wich i dont have yet

Comment: I will give you a vote up for your question to allow you to vote up for people :)